# File or directory not found error for command "/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth1 "on centos-5.11

Tags: virtual-machine

I am ruuning centos-5.11 inside vm .I want to change network configurations. but i am getting an error "no such file or directory found" when running this command  "/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth1 ".

how to resolve? please help..

Thanks.

Comment: Your question itself says the answer !!! please go through each directory one by one and check. That may help you.>!

Comment: This are network configurations. cant go through its directory because eth0  means they are devices configured in a network. It worked for eth0 but not for eth1.